# Is it possible to set activeforeground/activebackground using customtkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, frontend, customtkinter

I am able to use activeforeground and activebackground to change color in background/text when button is clicked in tkinter.

Is it possible to do the same thing in customtkinter as well? I have checked the website if similar context is available, however, could not see any.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From both the documentation and the GitHub webpage, I could not see any changes that would suggest this is possible.

You cannot have it on the button event function, so that the moment the button is clicked, the background and foreground is changed and then it is changed back to the normal. This is beacuse the the switch will be too fast and it does not work if you add sleep().

The closest work around that you can have is probably just to have it on the hover event as I belive the Hover event may be interfering with the changing of the colour in runtime straight away. If this is a deal breaker you may want to use PySide2/6 instead as they do have this exact custimastion readily availabe.

Also for anyone else interested in Custom Tkinter, make sure to use the GitHub page to see any progress or fucntions as it is mantained, the best documentation is from the Wiki found at:

https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki